# chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know this has been asked a lot of times and I have also tried all of the answers but it isn't working for me. I have tried option and PATH method on a simple script to extract title of a webpage and it worked. but with all of this code, it is giving me the said error

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

HEADERS = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
PATH = r"C:\Users\hp\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options , executable_path=PATH)

def get_current_url(url, jobTitle, location):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@Id="text-input-what"]').send_keys(jobTitle)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@Id="text-input-where"]').send_keys(location)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="jobsearch"]/button').click()
    except:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="whatWhereFormId"]/div[3]/button').click()
        current_url = driver.current_url
    return current_url

current_url = get_current_url('https://pk.indeed.com/', 'Python Developer', 'Karachi')
print(current_url)
```

> 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__      
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\de-projects\Indeed-scraper.py", line 31, in <module>
    current_url = get_current_url('https://pk.indeed.com/', 'Python Developer', 'Karachi')
  File "e:\de-projects\Indeed-scraper.py", line 15, in get_current_url
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Solution***

You can get rid of all driver, versions issues by using `ChromeDriverManager`

- If at all you are using ChromeDriverManager - Webdriver Manager for
  Python you don't have to explicitly download the `ChromeDriver` as it
  automatically gets downloaded.
- If you want to use the downloaded `ChromeDriver` you can avoid using
  `ChromeDriverManager - Webdriver Manager`

*Using `ChromeDriverManager` you can use the following code block:*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Downloading a specific version of [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home) you can use the following code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('C:/Users/hp/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

***Note***: If you are on `Linux / MAC O SX` system you need to strip the extension part i.e. `.exe` as it is applicable only for `windows` platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

First, you could add `C:\Users\hp\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe` to the system path. Follow the guide below.

https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Or second, when you use the r string, you need to change the slash like this. It should work if you flip it.

```
PATH = r"C:/Users/hp/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```py
PATH = r"C:\Users\hp\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options , executable_path=PATH)
```

Try

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

webdriver_service = Service('C:\Users\hp\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)
```