# I got error 'chromedriver.exe executable needs to be in PATH'

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

I am using colab. I am trying to use selenium with python. I looked at different threads regarding adding the chromedriver to the PATH, which I did, but I keep getting the same error. I get two messages:

1. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\bin\chromedriver.exe': 'C:\bin\chromedriver.exe'
2. WebDriverException: Message: 'C:\bin\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Here is my screenshot of error: [code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jh7F.png)

Comment: Have you checked that `C:\bin\chromedriver.exe` exists? And have you restarted your terminal and/or device after changing PATH?

Comment: Yes, it exists. I did not restart my terminal. Would that help?

Comment: Checkout this, will solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/74029548/11863448

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the path set up properly.
Lucky for you this is doable through code. I used to do this all the time to have a portable swing application that run selenium on a shared project that ran on every laptop without explaining this stuff to them

```
# assign ChromeDriver path to variable
chrome = "/Users/Administrator/Downloads/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chrome
```

I used to do it in Java but it should be doable on every language
https://www.approbotic.com/rpa/rpa/how-do-i-run-chrome-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python/#page-content

If you are using paths make sure that you are using the right arrows to indicate location \ isn't the same as \

[How to get an absolute file path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)