# Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I have made a program that was working just fine until one day it randomly started giving me this error:
Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
even though the "chromedriver" is in a path. I used this code:

```py
CHROME_PATH ='C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'C:\Users\Sahar\Desktop\bot\chromedriver.exe'
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH
 

browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

> this code is being ran in a exe file made using pyinstaller

Comment: Checkout this solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/74029548/11863448

Comment: @Akzy the same exact thing happened after i did what that question said.

Comment: The accepted answer in the question will solve your issue if you look into it as well.

Comment: Also the answer mentioned by @Prophet below is exactly correct and valid, that's why I upvoted it.

Comment: So could you please upvote my answer in that question and accept the below @Prophet answer, so other can also get benefit from them

Comment: @Akzy I upvoted your answer. Keyvan can't upvote since he has no enough reputation. Thanks!

Comment: I just returned the +1 :)  @Akzy

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `executable_path='chromedriver.exe'` try using the new approach `service=webdriver_service` as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
webdriver_service = Service('C:\Users\Sahar\Desktop\bot\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
```

Comment: I hit the exact same error, nothing changed.

Comment: Are you sure `chromedriver.exe` exists in the `C:\Users\Sahar\Desktop\bot\chromedriver.exe` path? Not zipped etc?

Comment: I'm so sorry this problem was made for another reason which i solved, your code was right, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `webdriver.Chrome` line:

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

the `executable_path` needs to point at the `chromedriver.exe`. Right now, it's looking at your project directory for `chromedriver.exe` and not finding it because it is in your desktop.