# Chromedriver needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is a recent error, just yesterday this wasn't happening and nothing changed as far as I'm aware.

I'm getting this error despite using ChromeDriverManager().install() and even tried manually downloading the chromedriver and using its path and the issue remains.

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

The error:

```
INFO:WDM:====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 106.0.5249
INFO:WDM:Current google-chrome version is 106.0.5249
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 106.0.5249
INFO:WDM:Get LATEST driver version for 106.0.5249
[WDM] - There is no [win32] chromedriver for browser 106.0.5249 in cache
INFO:WDM:There is no [win32] chromedriver for browser 106.0.5249 in cache
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 106.0.5249
INFO:WDM:Get LATEST driver version for 106.0.5249
[WDM] - Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/106.0.5249.61/chromedriver_win32.zip
INFO:WDM:Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/106.0.5249.61/chromedriver_win32.zip
[WDM] - Driver has been saved in cache [C:\Users\SteelHard\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\106.0.5249.61]
INFO:WDM:Driver has been saved in cache [C:\Users\SteelHard\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\106.0.5249.61]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 829, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1279, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(self._get_devnull())
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1062, in _get_devnull
    self._devnull = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nul'

then a bunch more random stuff from selenium which results in:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

What could be the issue, I've tried so many different ways to get this fixed...

Comment: Have you tried adding `executable_path` as an argument in the `webdriver.Chrome` instance?

Comment: @SalmanFarsi Yes, still same error. Also added the path to system variables...

Comment: and the path you've added is `C:\Users\SteelHard\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\106.0.5249.61`, correct?

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74029548/11863448 will surely resolve your issue

Comment: @SalmanFarsi No, I added the one used for the manual driver, I'll try adding that too

Comment: @Akzy that's literally what I'm doing in the code above? Doesn't work

Comment: @Steelhard2 - Please add the complete `code` then in the description

Comment: that is the complete code though, do you want me to add the imports and stuff? the driver.get and stuff is completely irrelevant since the program errors in setting up the webdriver right away

Comment: @SalmanFarsi yep added that one and still didn't work

Comment: @Steelhard2 - Yes, add the import , reload the project and check