# what is wrong with service in the following code?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to test my web page. I have the following code:

```
# Internet Explorer Browser version
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import IEDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Ie(service=Service(executable_path=IEDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

The said code gives the following error:

```
[WDM] - Downloading: 100%|█| 1.03M/1.03M [00:00<00:00, 19.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Ie(service=Service(executable_path=IEDriverManager().install()))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

What should I do, and what is the reason for the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line to below as you are using `IEDriverManager` in this case you do not need to define the `executable_path`

```
driver = webdriver.Ie(service=Service(IEDriverManager().install()))
```

You can find the more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74029548/11863448)

Comment: @person Are you still getting error after changing the code ?

Comment: yes its the same error as before @ akzy

Comment: Are you defining the path any where in the code as you had use executable_path ?

Comment: no i did not and it worked