# Problems with Chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

Getting started with using Chrome webdrivers and selenium. When I execute the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait




driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = \
                          r"C:\Users\payto\Downloads\chromedriver_win32.zip\chromedriver.exe")
```

I keep getting this error:

WebDriverException: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

I've looked up how to solve it, but anything I see says to install a webdriver...which I've already done. My Chrome version is 107 and that's the one I downloaded, so it should be working but it's not. Any tips?

Comment: Perhaps the simplest fix would be to put your chromedriver.exe file in the same folder as your python file. You would then not need to provide an `executable_path`. 

The only reason I suggest this is because the path you are providing points to a default downloads folder - so I'm assuming you don't really care where the chromedriver lives.

Comment: Use 'Webdriver Manager',  https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **webdriver_manager** instead of constantly setting executable_path and chromedriver yourself.

For chrome driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

it will automatically download the appropriate chromedriver. if it's already loaded, it finds it in the cache and uses it directly.

Answer (score 0):

***Solution***

You can get rid of all driver versions issues by using `ChromeDriverManager`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

OR Fixing the issue in your existing code like ..
Downloading a specific version of [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home) you can use the following code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('C:/Users/hp/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

You can find more discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74029548/11863448), hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to install the Chrome Browser on you machine.

Go to https://www.google.com/intl/en_en/chrome/, download and install it.

It is needed to run Selenium/ Chrome.